# Alterar a cor do edittext e de seleção no edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, edittext

Estou utilizando um AutoCompleteTextView e um EditText, para email e password, respectivamente. É possível alterar a cor deles? Segue imagem abaixo:
Alterar a cor de seleção e a cor na tela:

[image: Alterar a cor de seleção e a cor na tela]

XML:`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#D3D3D3"
                android:textSize="12dp"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#D3D3D3"
                android:textSize="12dp"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

`
Obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente isto, adicione estes estilos no seu `style.xml`:

```
<style name="StyledTilEditTextTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#e6ffffff</item> // Cor padrão da linha
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#faffffff</item> // Cor linha e texto quando recebe foco
</style>

<style name="StyledTilEditText">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/StyledTilEditTextTheme</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#c8ffffff</item> // Cor texto(hint) sem foco
</style>
```

E no seu `TextInputLayout` referencie o estilo que acabou de criar:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout 
   style="@style/StyledTilEditText"
   ... Seu width e blablabla>

   ... Seu EditText

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Explicando(pra quem não entendeu):

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">#e6ffffff</item> // É a cor padrão da linha que fica embaixo do EditText

<item name="colorControlActivated">#faffffff</item> // Cor da linha e do texto hint(no seu caso email) quando receber foco(clique)

<item name="android:textColorHint">#c8ffffff</item> // É a cor normal do texto hint(email)
```

O exemplo acima vai ficar com as cores assim:
[image: exemplo]

Comment: Então, eu tinha já um style personalizado, ele altera a cor da linha, mas do texto "email por exemplo", que continua em preto e a seleção ainda em "rosa".

Comment: Voce tentou usar o codigo que coloquei

Comment: Esses dias tambem estava procurando como alterar isso e depois de pesquisar muitos topicos consegui juntar isso ai kk

Comment: Nesse meu exemplo as cores são brancas pois meu fundo é preto.

Comment: O Bruno, valeu, funcionou sim, meu cerebro que foi lento na explicação aí. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Que nada, também demorei muito pra consegui fazer isso funcionar kkkk